# C# Regex match multiple words in a string

Tags: c#, regex

How can I find all the matches in a string using a regular expression run in C#?

I want to find all matches in the below example string.
Example:

```
inputString: Hello (mail) byebye (time) how are you (mail) how are you (time)
```

I want to match `(mail)` and `(time)` from the example. Including parentheses`(` and `)`.

In attempting to solve this, I've writtent the following code.

```
string testString = @"(mail)|(time)";  

Regex regx = new Regex(Regex.Escape(testString), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
List<string> mactches = regx.Matches(inputString).OfType<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).Distinct().ToList();

foreach (string match in mactches)
{
    //Do something
}
```

Is the pipe(`|`) used for the logical `OR` condition?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using `Regex.Escape(testString)` is going to escape your pipe character, turning

```
@"(mail)|(time)"
```

effectively into

```
@"\(mail\)\|\(time\)".
```

Thus, your regex is looking for the literal `"(mail)|(time)"`.

If all of your matches are as simple as words surrounded by parens, I would build the regex like this:

```
List<string> words   = new List<string> { "(mail)", "(time)", ... };
string       pattern = string.Join("|", words.Select(w => Regex.Escape(w)));
Regex        regex   = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 4):

Escape the parentheses in your test string:

```
string testString = @"\(mail\)|\(time\)";
```

Remove `Regex.Escape`:

```
Regex regx = new Regex(testString, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Output *(includes parentheses)*:

```
(mail)
(time)
```

The reason `Regex.Escape` isn't working in your case is that it escapes the `|` character as well:

> Escapes a minimal set of metacharacters (\, *, +, ?, |, {, [, (, ), ^, $, ., #, and  whitespace) by replacing them with their \ codes.

Comment: Wow... correct. but why is the use of Escape than? because i want to build the testString dynamically from a list of words for example:

(mail)
(time)
(this)
(that)

I thought i could escape them useing the Regex.Escape. Weird! @Grant Winney

Comment: I think because it ends up escaping your `|` character too.

Comment: @Nisho, use `Escape` by all means, something like `String.Join("|", myListOfWords.Select(Regex.Escape))`.

Comment: Feel free to use this in your answer if you believe it adds value :)

Comment: @decPL Looks like FishBasketGordo had the same thought as you. :)